# ArgumentError: Invalid arguments! for rails csv import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, csv-import

I'm trying to import data via a csv file in my rails application. whenever I try I keep getting an error stating `Invalid arguments!`.  I don't really get any other errors, and my stack trace really hasn't given me anything helpful.  If anyone would know have any clues, I'd be grateful for sure!

My error is happening in the controller.

```
  def import
    Downtown.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to @downtown, notice: "Products imported."  
  end
```

When I put in a breakpoint right before the import, I look into the The `params[:file]`, and it gives me.

```
[7] pry(#<DowntownsController>)> params[:file]
=> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbfeb871fd8
 @content_type="text/csv",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"downtowns.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n",
 @original_filename="downtowns.csv",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/dz/106qqn2s25d8tbrty82wt77r0000gr/T/RackMultipart20200405-7860-1ezpt61.csv>>
```

As for the rest of my code, I'm at

In my view

```
= form_tag import_downtowns_path, multipart: true do
  = file_field_tag :file
  = submit_tag "import"
```

My route

```
  resources :downtowns do
    collection { post :import }
  end
```

My model

```
  def import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Downtown.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you try passing the complete file rather than. just the file.path? `CSV.foreach(file, headers: true)`

Comment: Please post the full error message including the stacktrace.